# Cleaning Exhaust Manifold

Tags: exhaust, exhaust-manifold

I would like to clean up my rusty cast iron exhaust manifolds. What is the best coating to use after they have been thoroughly cleaned, ceramic coating, powder coating, or heat resistant paint to withstand temperatures up to 1400 degrees F?

Comment: Only ceramic. On heavy sustained load they could reach 1500 F.

Comment: I restore cars, I sand blast the manifolds and use high heat BBQ paint (5-6 heavy coats), they hold up for many many years. Regardless of the coating sandblast them first for best results.

Comment: Nickel coating?

Answer (score 1):

I use Tremclad High Heat Enamel in spray can. It is rated to 1200F. The flat black dissipates the heat into the engine compartment, while the flat white holds the heat in, allowing the O2 sensor and catalytic to get up to operating temp more quickly.